# OrderBy + foreach + dataRef does not work in Firestore/Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Edited] Corrected typo

Assuming that we have two DB called `matches` and `teams`.

- `matches` has `date`, `teamARef` and `teamBRef` as fields.

  - `date` is a datetime which **we want to orderBy** this time.
  - `teamARef` and `teamBRef` are dataRef which are obtained in the code below.
- `teams` can have a `name` field, etc.

`orderBy` actually works fine. `console.log(doc.data().date)` below shows matches in order.

But in `teamARef.get().then(){}` block, it does not work anymore.

Early matches tend to appear early but it is not well ordered.

Maybe this happens because `then()` is not done necessarily in the same order as `orderBy`?

## code

```js
var db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("matches").orderBy("date").limit(20) 
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

            // **IN ORDER**
            console.log(doc.data().date)

            var teamARef = db.collection("teams").doc(doc.data().teamARef.id)
            var teamBRef = db.collection("teams").doc(doc.data().teamBRef.id)

            teamARef.get().then(function(docA){
                teamBRef.get().then(function(docB){

                    var nameA = docA.data().name
                    var nameB = docB.data().name

                    // **NOT IN ORDER!**
                    console.log(nameA + ', ' + nameB + ' @' + doc.data().date)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

## e.g. of output

It appears in this order.

```
2017-01-01
2017-01-02
2017-01-03
2017-01-04
2017-01-05

BAK, BIA @2017-01-01
EWN, ALE @2017-01-03
ENO, VNI @2017-01-02
LNE, LWM @2017-01-05
BIC, AIC @2017-01-04
```

Comment: can you please explain more clear. Do you mean that `doc.data().date` in your last line differ from previous value that you printed in console.log?

Comment: Have you noted that you define twice teamARef?  teamRefB is not defined and you should normally get an error. Probably a typo in the question.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec it was a typo, thanks

Comment: [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) is explained that if you get partial results the order by should be by the criteria of the selection if it was with ranges

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to var the teamBRef but you did teamARef twice here:

```
var teamARef = db.collection("teams").doc(doc.data().teamARef.id)
var teamARef = db.collection("teams").doc(doc.data().teamARef.id)
```